# Lambda to count total items in a list of lists

Tags: c#

I know it can be done with a foreach but does anyone know if there is a lambda expression to count the total items in a list of lists?  I want to do this using a => expression

```
            int totalitems = 0;
            foreach (List<item> list in ListOfItemLists)
            {
                totalitems += list.Count();
            }
```

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534734(v=vs.100).aspx) on the outer list:

```
ListOfItemLists.Sum(l => l.Count());
```